# How to print tuple "RAW"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I know my code it's a mess, but I need to get the desired output for an assignment.
I didn't learn anything about tuple output I mean how to manipulate...
But all that I found on internet is about tuples like: ('A', 10) with a key and a value.
And for what I understand I have a tuple with two values.

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
raw_dat = list()
time = list()
hour = list()
dic = dict()
rdy = list()

for line in handle :
    if not line.startswith("From") : continue
    if line.startswith("From:") : continue
    raw_dat.append(line.split())

for item in raw_dat :
    item = item[5]
    time.append(item)

for data in time :
    hour.append(data[0:2])

for hr in hour:
    dic[hr] = dic.get(hr, 0) + 1
for tm in sorted(dic.items()) :
    print(tm)
```

My output atm...

```
('04', 3)
('06', 1)
('07', 1)
('09', 2)
('10', 3)
('11', 6)
('14', 1)
('15', 2)
('16', 4)
('17', 2)
('18', 1)
('19', 1)
```

Desired output...

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean: ‘print(tm[0], tm[1])’?

Comment: Thank you very much... great answer short and the perfect solution. Really thank you.

Comment: `print(*tm)` would do it

Comment: In this code, `for line in handle :
    if not line.startswith("From") : continue
    if line.startswith("From:") : continue
    raw_dat.append(line.split())`, do you think `raw_dat.append(line.split())` will get executed?

Comment: @JoeFerndz . I don't know what you mean... At first I thought it was a trick question. But I cut(#) the line of code and the whole thing wouldn't work. So I would like to know what you mean by that. It get's executed and it's an important part(at least for me) of the code.

Comment: And @PatrickArtner that's even better. What I learned is the smaller the code the better it is... And print(*tm) works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero, looks like you want to process the rows only if the data starts with `From` and ignore all other rows including `From:` or `To` or `To:` or any other combination. This could have been achieved with `if line.startswith("From") and line[4] != ':':`

Comment: @JoeFerndz That's great, I'm a two weeks beginner of coding. I'll have a look of your line of code more in detail tomorrow, I'm interested on learning what that does. For the moment that looks like Dutch to me. Thank you very much for the comments and the help.

Comment: what that code does is as follows: look for lines that starts with `From`. Since you want to ignore all `From:`, its checking if the 5th position (index = 4) is `:` and if it is, then its skipping. That results in rows with `From ` or `From-` or anything but `From:`. It also ignores all rows that do not start with `From`

Comment: @JoeFerndz So this bit of code         and line[4] != ':':          works like:                         
     and if line.index(4) != ':':     I think I understand the first part until the ! I don't understand why would you use ! and the last :       If you would be able to explain me would be great. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @quamrana for helping me...
This is the solution given...

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
raw_dat = list()
time = list()
hour = list()
dic = dict()

for line in handle :
    if not line.startswith("From") : continue
    if line.startswith("From:") : continue
    raw_dat.append(line.split())

for item in raw_dat :
    item = item[5]
    time.append(item)

for data in time :
    hour.append(data[0:2])

for hr in hour:
    dic[hr] = dic.get(hr, 0) + 1
for tm in sorted(dic.items()) :
    print(tm[0], tm[1])
```

original :

```
print(tm)
```

solution (1) :

```
print(tm[0], tm[1])
```

solution (2) :

```
print(*tm)
```

Comment: How about `print(*tm)`?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Works the same as print(tm[0], tm[1]). Thank you very much.

Comment: I know, it's just shorter and more generic. More 'python-ish' if you will

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski True, looks much more like I know what I'm doing. Thank you very much for that. Tomorrow I'll have a look of what that " * " does in general.